# Changes to Windows System Disk to Be Able to Boot from USB

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, usb, sata

I have a regular Windows system disk connected via SATA and booting as drive C, no issues, everything normal, on a regular whatever (desktop, laptop, etc.).

If I disconnect the drive from the internal SATA port and connect the drive to a SATA to USB adapter and then plug the combo into a USB port, what changes need to be made to the Windows disk, so that the computer can boot into Windows from the USB port. The procedure would be to press F11 to get to the boot menu and then selecting the USB hard disk.

The changes should be reversible. I have no issues doing whatever to the disk prior to plugging into the USB port.

I was using Windows 10 (Pro? Enterprise?) with the April 2018 update.

Why? I was given this task as an assignment, just I do not know what I would need to do to resolve the issue. I tried the experiment with CentOS and that works fine; Mac too, though that is obvious as Mac is BSD Linux, just Windows does not work.

Note:
I did see the video on how to create a bootable USB drive with Windows on it from scratch, but I want to take an existing Windows SATA disk and temporarily be able to boot from that drive, when connected to the system via a USB port. There may or may not be another drive plugged into the motherboard. That should not matter, as I specified the boot device as the USB SATA device.

What happens now is that Windows boots part way, throws a blue screen, and then a few seconds later reboots.

Thoughts?

Comment: A school assignment, or a work project? If it's a school assignment the goal is that you need to learn how to do this yourself, and if we were to give you the answer it would be hurting you. If it's a work project what kind of computer is this, what is the end goal or purpose of this project?

Comment: @music2myear Is not everything in life a "school assignment" be that from an accredited university, work place, or just SOHK? The direct answer is the latter. The purpose is to be able to boot off the USB. Based on my current understanding, the task is to force Windows to think that there is a configuration change. The purpose of this project is to be able to boot a system disk from the USB port temporarily.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment. I am constantly learning, and I know the value of not simply knowing facts, but knowing where to find them. Good use of resources is usually a sign of wisdom. However, in the common understanding of "school" the method of learning is different, and there are a steady stream of people who ask questions here where they have been given an assignment by a teacher and have simply passed that along to us, not trying to even begin to solve it themselves. For their own benefit, to force them to actually learn, we usually decline to answer these questions.